# How to get the ALL the values from the listview? android

Tags: android, listview, view

Im talkin the views in the displayed listview.  In other words, I want to be able to get all the edited rows at once.  I have no interest in the ones from the adapter.  I can do that with the code below.

```
mCount = this.getListView().getCount();
ListAdapter a= (ListAdapter) this.getListAdapter(); 
for(int i =0; i< mCount; i++ ){
   View curr = a.getView(i,null,null);
   TextView tvCheckitem = (TextView) curr.findViewById(R.id.CHECKLISTITEM);
   RadioButton rbCheckitem = (RadioButton) curr.findViewById(R.id.rbFAIL);
   boolean blah = rbCheckitem.isChecked();
   String blah2 = blah + "hi";
}
```

Comment: and what is your specific problem?

Comment: if you can do..then what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is the code I posted gets me the views from the adapter.  I want the views that are currently in the listview.  Which is after the adapter.  In other words I want the user to be able to change multiple rows and save them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

BY your question it seems you want to fetch only records which have been edited, I assume you have been implemented list in multiple selection mode, you can get values currently checked by:

```
mCount = this.getListView().getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = this.getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < mCount ; i++)
 if (checked.get(i)) {
  String item = cont_list.get(i);
  /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom adapter which will help you take the all position at once.If you can use custom adapter your owns then fine else tell me.I will give you code of custom adapter which can help you more.
Best 
V.k

Comment: I want the user to be able to change multiple rows and save them all at once.

Comment: http://rorraja.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-use-listview-using-custom.html  this link will help you to make the custom list view.When you will cilck on any view in getView() method then at that time count the all postion and use as you want... I am suggesting this answer as i think that you want all position when you click on any one view..am i right???